# Attributable Risk vs Absolute Risk Reduction

Tags: absolute-risk, population-attributable-fraction

I am hoping to understand the difference between attributable risk and absolute risk reduction. Mathematically, the two entities seem equivalent, but the formulas for calculating their confidence interval are quite different (https://www2.ccrb.cuhk.edu.hk/stat/confidence interval/CI for relative risk.htm, https://www2.ccrb.cuhk.edu.hk/stat/confidence interval/CI for ratio.htm). I presumed that attributable risk is used in prospective studies in the context of discussing risk ratio, while ARR is used in retrospective studies in the context of discussing odds ratio.

I appreciate your feedback and comment.

Comment: Both links are broken.

Comment: @GastroGuy Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.